# Understanding Math.max

Tags: javascript

I've been playing a coding game, and recently found this solution to a coding challenge, but I can't really understand it.

I've tried reading up on `Math.max` and but I can't wrap my head around it.

What is happening in this code?

```js
var n = 6; 
var items = [6, 2, 1, 6, 0, 9]; 
var high  = items[0];
var loss = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    var v = parseInt(items[i]);
    high = Math.max(high, v);
    loss = Math.max(loss, high - v);
}

console.log(-1 * loss);
```

Comment: What do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: `Math.max` returns the greater of two numbers.

Comment: parseInt is unnecessary since it's already a number

Comment: I know what `Math.max` does (it's not that hard) but I am at a loss what this code is supposed to do. What was the challenge?

Comment: Array starts at 0 (not 1) so you are actually skipping the first `6`, my bad (missed the `high = items[0]`)

Comment: @Endless `high = items[0]` that's why

Comment: Not enough `parseInt`, you should use `v = parseInt(parseInt(items[i]))`, `high = parseInt(Math.max(parseInt(high), parseInt(v)))`, etc. Now seriously, **`parseInt` is harmful** when used with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these, it's pretty helpful to output to console the variables to better understand what's happening:

```js
var n = 6; 
var items = [6, 2, 1, 6, 0, 9]; 
var high  = items[0];
var loss = 0;
    
for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  console.log("[Roll " + i + "]");
  var v = parseInt(items[i]);
  high = Math.max(high, v);
  loss = Math.max(loss, high - v);
  console.log("v: " + v + "\nhigh: " + high + "\nloss: " + loss);
}
    
console.log(-1 * loss);
```

As others have mentioned in the comments, the `Math.max` is very simple, just returns the largest number of the arguments given to it.

For example:

```
> Math.max(5, 7, 9202902)
< 9202902
```

Comment: @AndrewL. I think the problem there is the question is unclear. OP wants to understand `Math.max` and Rani does answer that. However, OP is also confused about the snippet and showing how to debug it also answers that. Sure, going through it line by line will also be an answer but we don't know what OP finds confusing in it just that apparently it is. Adding a simple log statement makes the code pretty self explanatory, though.